# Ghost line drawing over the top of chart in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

In react-jsx-highcharts, when all series are off toggled off via the legend, but one is toggled back on, if the chart data updates at the same time, a "Ghost" line draws across the graph. Is there an option in the Highcharts API to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Hi @Jason Y, I recommend you to use the officially supported Highcharts wrapper for React: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

Comment: Well I can't just switch. This is widespread at where I work. Also, this doesn't answer the question.